# Can't deploy in production React/nodejs website 'cause socket GET 404/500

Tags: sockets, ip, cross-domain, port, production-environment

CLIENT CONNECTION (from a middleware react redux)

```
import ioClient from 'socket.io-client';
case SOCKET_CONNECT:
var socketConnection=ioClient('http://163.172.89.215:80')
store.getState().connexion.socket=socketConnection;
```

SERVER CONFIGURATION NODEJS

```
const express = require('express')
const socket = require('socket.io')
const Server = require('http').Server;


const app = express()
const server = Server(app)
const io = socket(server)

//Route to check if i'm connected
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Connecté au serveur')
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, DELETE , OPTION')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    next()
})

// Gestion erreurs
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const err = new Error('Not found')
    err.status = 404
    next(err)
})

// PORT de travail du serveur
server.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 8000')
})
```

I try more or less everything and cannot work ... 163.172.89.215 is the true IP of my website to be deployed 
Get this error or sometime 404

```
vendors.js:57 GET http://163.172.89.215/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MXOYEJY 500 (Internal Server Error)...
```

Thanks for your help :D